# Type-graphql typegoose Cannot return null for non-nullable field UserEntity.id

Tags: typescript, mongoose, graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

Hi everyone!

```js
import { modelOptions, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';

@ObjectType()
@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { versionKey: false } })
export class UserEntity {
  @Field()
  @prop()
  public email?: string;
  @Field()
  @prop()
  public firstName?: string;
  @Field(() => ID)
  @prop()
  public id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  @Field()
  @prop()
  public lastName?: string;
}
```

```
mutation Register {
  register(password: "password1234", email: "mail", lastName: "lasr", firstName: "first") {
    id
  }
}
```

I'm using `type-graphl` and `typegoose` to provide an `UserEntity` as a result of a mutation. After creating a user in the database there is an autogenerated _id in the document as expected. The result of the create function has a `id` property having a string representation of `id`. The mutation works as expected, but if I query for id I get this exception:

`Cannot return null for non-nullable field UserEntity.id.`

How do I solve this? What decorators do I have to use to see the proper `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed `id` to `_id` and removed `@prop()` from the property. This way one can access the generated `_id` from the database.

```js
import { modelOptions, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';

@ObjectType()
@modelOptions({
  schemaOptions: {
    versionKey: false,
  },
})
export class UserEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  public _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  @Field()
  @prop()
  public email: string;
  @Field()
  @prop()
  public firstName: string;
  @Field()
  @prop()
  public lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: as a note, more information can be found at typegoose's documentation [Change _id Type](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/change-id-type)